# EC2 Grab and save data on auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I make a fresh EC2 instance which is just booted from auto scaling group grab and save sensitive .env data such as db credentials, encryption keys etc'?

Comment: Where do you want to grab it from and where do you want to save it to?

Comment: lets say s3/any other private url and save it as a '.env' file on my machine [specific path]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure that in user data settings when you are creating a new instance. Check this screenshot below.

You can add a curl command there. Some thing like this.

```
curl -o <directory you need to copy>/* https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/test.dev
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An option could be the User Data section on the Advanced Details accordion (bottom of the page) during the launch config creation, but I recommend to use git (or similar) to download the config/other sensitive data, because injecting an ENV variable during the startup which contains the name of the branch (which could act also as a stage name) will make the whole stuff to work on environment/stage independent, and you need to maintain only one AMI.

Another option could be a docker image build, and during the startup of the container (or during the image build), you can also inject ENV variables (or mount an Elastic File System to the container) which are containing the config elements.

A third option could be to put together a CloudFormation stack, which will configure the start/update of the stack to pull the config elements to the stack.

The fourth option is to use OpsWorks (Chef) to do the configuration updates on a regular period (cron/service) or by triggered automation (some CI/CD tools like Jenkins, Bamboo, Travis could do this easily).